# glassfish-web.xml vs domain.xml for alternatedocroot

Tags: resources, glassfish, glassfish-3

I need an alternatedocroot property to have my uploaded images outside of the app directory.  I have it working correctly inside glassfish-web.xml like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=c:/development/mm_uploads" description="Uploaded Images"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

My issue with that implementation is that I would have this file checked in to the codebase, which won't work well when buildling a war for other environments (different dir paths).

I tried putting in domain.xml (figuring that would be server specific, rather than in the codebase), but couldn't get it to work.  I put it as a child of domain, but no luck.  No errors, it just didn't work.

Any ideas?  I should be able to use the same property setting in domain.xml, right?

If that's bad practice, are there other alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope, the alternate docroot is a property of the web application and not of the server, so it wont work in any other file

Comment: Be careful to leave the area "default-web-module" EMPTY !

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I couldn't get glassfish-web.xml alternatedocroot_n to work.  However, when I put the same entry in domain.xml using the Glassfish Admin Console Virtual Servers --> server Additional Properties, the alternatedocroot_n worked immediately. (after a server restart). FYI: I tried to use a symbolic link but that didn't work.

I am using Glassfish 3.1.2 running on Linux 5.  The alternatedocroot points to an ExtJs 4.0.7 library.

**domain.xml:**

```
    <virtual-server id="server" network-listeners="http-listener-1,http-listener-2">
      <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/extjs.4.0.7/* dir=/usr/lib/js"></property>
    </virtual-server>
```

This equates to /usr/lib/js/extjs.4.0.7/...

Hope this helps someone..

**index.jsp:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/extjs.4.0.7/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs.4.0.7/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```